# GeoTools Oracle spatial plugin samples / documentation

Tags: geotools, oracle-spatial

I plan to use GeoTools and I saw that there is an Oracle plugin available, but the documentation is not very detailed.  Are there any examples or documentation available to access the functionality of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle datastore works just like any of the other [GeoTools data stores](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/datastore.html) so just work through the [tutorials](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/index.html) (esp. [feature](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html) and [query](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/filter/query.html)) and you will be fine.